# How to check if a number is an absolute integer using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to check if a number is an absolute integer.

I seem to be easily able to convert a number to an absint `abs( intval( $_POST['number'] ) );` but can't figure out how to check for one:

```
// pseudo code
if ( is_asbint( $_POST['number'] ) ) {
   echo 'yay';
}
```

Comment: `if(is_int($number) AND $number > 0) { echo 'yay'; }`

Comment: @Rizier123 if `is_int()` will return true for negative numbers, then no.

Comment: There is also `is_numeric()` which will return true for `is_numeric("1")` and `is_numeric(1)`

Comment: If you don't want negatives than also `if(is_numeric($num) and $num > 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many logical ways to check that, but one particular function - [ctype_digit()](https://secure.php.net/ctype_digit) - happens to do *exactly* what you want.
It's probably worth noting that I'm saying "happens" and "what you *want*" for two specific reasons:

1. `ctype_digit()` is designed to check if a **string** value (it won't work on values that are actually of the *integer* type) consists entirely of digit *characters*, meaning that it won't accept the minus/dash sign.
2. Any `$_POST` value (excluding arrays) is guaranteed to be a *string* unless you've modified it from within your code - user inputs always come as strings ... you're just calling it an "integer" here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that function, and thanks for the explanation.